# Tags: Name in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to put count index with alphabet in Terraform. For eg I have 3 subnets and I want to pass tags Name as subnet A, subnet B and subnet C. How can I do so?

```
variable "public_subnet_tags" {
  default = {
    Name = [
      "Production DMZ Subnet A",
      "Production DMZ Subnet B",
      "Production DMZ Subnet C",
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show demonstrating your issue?

Comment: `variable "public_subnet_tags" {
 
default = {
 
     Name = ["Production DMZ Subnet A", "Production DMZ Subnet B", "Productio    n DMZ Subnet C"]
   
    }

  }`

Comment: yes https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/blob/master/main.tf. this it the link of the module I'm using. I'm not supposed to edit the module.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {

  count = length(var.public_subnet_tags["Name"])
 
  # ...
    
  tags = {
    Name = var.public_subnet_tags["Name"][count.index]
  }
}
```